# How to use setImageResource to set a image with ViewHolder

Tags: java, arraylist, android-viewholder, android-imagebutton

Dose anyone know why setImageResource cannot get image from my getImage method?

It gives me and error message saying setImageResource cannot be applied to (jave.lang.string).

I've tried changing movieImage value into a Int but it then gives me another list of errors. Should I stick to setImageResource or is that another way I can set the image in my listview from my array?

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position ,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    setupImageLoader();

    //get the movie information
    String movieName = getItem(position).getTitle();
    String movieDuration = getItem(position).getMovieLength();
    String movieRating = getItem(position).getMovieRating();
    String movieImage = getItem(position).getCoverArt();



    //Create the movie object with the information
    objectMovieListView objectMovieListView = new objectMovieListView(movieName, movieDuration, movieRating, movieImage);

    //create the view result for showing the animation
    final View result;

    //ViewHolder object
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.movieName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieName);
        holder.movieDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieDuration);
        holder.movieRating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieRating);
        holder.movieImage = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieListImageButton);

        result = convertView;
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    int defaultImage = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/icons8_image_moviepicture", null,mContext.getPackageName());

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(defaultImage)
            .showImageOnFail(defaultImage)
            .showImageOnLoading(defaultImage).build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(movieImage, holder.movieImage, options);


    holder.movieName.setText(objectMovieListView.getMovieName());
    holder.movieDuration.setText(objectMovieListView.getMovieDuration());
    holder.movieRating.setText(objectMovieListView.getMovieRating());
    //holder.movieImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.avengers_infinity_war_poster);
    holder.movieImage.setImageResource(objectMovieListView.getMovieImage());

    return convertView;
}
```

Here's the Class where I store all my get and set methods

```
    public class objectMovieListView {

private String movieImage;


public objectMovieListView(String movieImage) {

    this.movieImage = movieImage;

public String getMovieImage() {
    return movieImage;
}

public void setMovieImage(String movieImage) {
    this.movieImage = movieImage;
}
```

}

Comment: Help please I'm still stuck with the same problem.